# node.js flatfile database using a CSV file and an array?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, csv, flat-file

I have been using SQL for quite a while now, for a node.js project, I wanted to make the package smaller, and easier to manage, I thought by getting rid of MYSQl I can have put the database as part of the server, using a CSV file, or or something similar, and a variable array, how could I archive this?

I am yet to try any code, but this is how I am planning on going about it at the moment:

A basic express web server using the GET/POST requests, import a CSV file to a array, then do a basic variable comparison,  like say, if (vararray === "foo"){
return "foo" exists in the database.}

I am still relatively new to javascript.

Comment: I have tried other methods, but do not wish to use any third party modules.

Comment: Am I going to get no answer because I don't know what code to try?

Comment: This question is beyond vague and unclear.

Comment: If you are going to use node.js you need to get into the ideas behind it as a platform. So saying that you won't use modules is a bit off since everyone uses modules so you get the best code without having to reinvent everything. If you want serverless SQL, use sqlite or similar. If you want an answer, you will need to make the question more specific.